# reinstalled npm - now npm works only with sudo (osx high sierra)

Tags: node.js, npm-install, macos-high-sierra

I was unable to install electron in my system (was getting postinstall error). So I thought let me uninstall and reinstall node and npm. I tried [this gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) and couldnt install npm - that erred out. So I went to node js [website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) and downloaded versions: node 8.9.0 & npm 5.6.0. While I now have node and npm back, no npm installation works without a sudo. Funny thing, I get the same electron installation error. I tried fixing the sudo problem using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo) but no help. Please advise!

Screenshot of the npm error:

[image]

Screenshot of the electron installation error:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you are running the npm install where you have read and write access to the folder then `sudo` is not required

Comment: Go to your home folder `cd ~` and tell us the permissions of the npm files in your home directory `ls -la | grep npm`.

Comment: @zero298 .npm has permission drwxrwxrwx . .npmrc has -rwxrwxrwx